# How to store/retrieve tree structure in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

First of all I know this article https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/applications/data-models-tree-structures/.

However I need to retrieve multiple levels of tree structure.
For example for data:

```
{ doc: "a", children: ["b", "c"] }
{ doc: "b", children: ["d"] }
{ doc: "c", children: ["e"] }
{ doc: "d", children: [] }
{ doc: "e", children: ["f"] }
{ doc: "f", children: [] }
```

I have to retrieve full tree of doc "a":

```
a
 b
  d
 c
  e
   f
```

Is it possible in mongoDB?

Comment: I think you need to be clearer

Comment: For given document I want to retrieve all its children along with children of each child and so on.

Comment: dos your traverse order matter, i.e. abdcef?   or  it can also be acefbd ?

Comment: @user606521 Keep also in mind that MongoDB 3.4 has graph operator (https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-23725)

Comment: @DanieleTassone this exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since MongoDB 3.4 you can use $graphLookup

*The stage matches the connectFromField of one document to the connectToField of other documents in the collection. Then, for any matching document, the $graphLookup uses the connectFromField of the matching document to match to the the connectToField of other documents, and continues until no new documents are encountered or until a specified depth*

https://docs.mongodb.com/master/release-notes/3.4-reference/#pipe._S_graphLookup

Answer (score 1):

You can try hacking an aggregation pipeline that uses the [**`$lookup`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#pipe._S_lookup) and **[`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/)** operators as follows:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        "$unwind": {
            "path": "$children",
            "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true
        }
    },
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "test",
            "localField": "children",
            "foreignField": "doc",
            "as": "child"
        }
    },
    {
        "$unwind": {
            "path": "$child",
            "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true
        }
    },
    {
        "$unwind": {
            "path": "$child.children",
            "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true
        }
    },    
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "test",
            "localField": "child.children",
            "foreignField": "doc",
            "as": "child.child"
        }
    },
    {
        "$unwind": {
            "path": "$child.child",
            "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true
        }
    },
    {
        "$unwind": {
            "path": "$child.child.children",
            "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true
        }
    },
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "test",
            "localField": "child.child.children",
            "foreignField": "doc",
            "as": "child.child.child"
        }
    },
    {
        "$unwind": {
            "path": "$child.child.child",
            "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true
        }
    },
    {
        "$unwind": {
            "path": "$child.child.child.children",
            "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true
        }
    },    
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$doc",
            "children": { "$push": "$child" }
        }
    },
    { "$match": { "_id": "a" } }
])
```

**Sample Output**

```
{
    "_id" : "a",
    "children" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("58204f0cd3cda4b4b1adadfb"),
            "doc" : "b",
            "children" : "d",
            "child" : {
                "_id" : ObjectId("58204f0cd3cda4b4b1adadfd"),
                "doc" : "d"
            }
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("58204f0cd3cda4b4b1adadfc"),
            "doc" : "c",
            "children" : "e",
            "child" : {
                "_id" : ObjectId("58204f0cd3cda4b4b1adadfe"),
                "doc" : "e",
                "children" : "f",
                "child" : {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("58204f0cd3cda4b4b1adadff"),
                    "doc" : "f"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: This doen't work for a tree with more than 3 levels right?

Comment: It works for as many tree levels, just have to include the corresponding `$lookup` and `$unwind` pipelines to get the desired structure though you may face some peformance penalties with that many pipelines

Comment: Like what @DanieleTassone said, you may have to use [`$graphLookup`](http://guyharrison.squarespace.com/blog/2016/8/24/graph-lookup-in-mongodb-33.html) in MongoDB 3.3.8 for this.